# Expression C# with Math.Ceiling

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, expression, rounding

Hi so i have datatable where display minimum stock, stock and quantity per 1 carton. And i want to add a column where it calculate how many CARTON which we order. this is my formula:

```
dt.Columns["QuantityOrder"].Expression = "(MinimumStock-Stock)/ QuantityPerCarton";
```

Well because i want to do for example the following: If MinimumStock = 4 , Stock = 1 and QuantityPerCarton = 12. I want QuantityOrder = 1 Even it is < 1 and >0. So i tried this:

```
dt.Columns["QuantityOrder"].Expression = Math.Ceiling("(MinimumStock-Stock)/ QuantityPerCarton");
```

But it has a build error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)' has some invalid arguments
```

and

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'decimal'
```

What should i do? This is a datatable and written in c#

**Update**: the datatype is **double** in case if **int** is rounding it to 0.

**Update 2**: Stock will **never** be more than minimum stock because i filtered it with sql

Comment: you are attempting to get the Ceiling of your expression string, rather than  using a ceiling function in your expression

Comment: `"(MinimumStock-Stock)/ QuantityPerCarton"` is a string, not an expression.

Comment: so i should do this?"Math.Ceiling(((MinimumStock-Stock) - 1) / QuantitéParCarton)"

Comment: the list of operators you can use in an expression is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but iI cant see a way to do Ceiling

Comment: oh there is IIF you could do that

Comment: @Ewan how to do with IIF then?

Comment: see my answer below. I'm assuming you dont want to order any when the stock is greater than the minimun stock level?

Comment: oh wait i slightly misinterepeted you question, ill edit my answer on sec

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the calc using the inline if operator and the modulo function %

```
string exp = "IIF(Stock > MinimumStock, 0, ((MinimumStock - (MinimumStock-Stock % QuantityPerCarton))/QuantityPerCarton)+1)"
dt.Columns["QuantityOrder"].Expression = exp
```

Comment: really, I would get all the data back into an object list and then you can use  the full range of .net math functions

Comment: Stock will never be more than minimum stock because i filtered it with sql

Comment: well that would be complicated when i just want to round to ceiling

Comment: sorry i misread your question thought it was the <0 problem. changed to add the ceiling via modulo

Comment: i don't really understand (MinimumStock - (MinimumStock-Stock % QuantityPerCarton)/QuantityPerCarton)+1, because it gives me 4.75

Comment: I may have got the brackets wrong. the idea is the moduls gives you the remainer, so take this off the otigonal value before dividing should give you a whole number